# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, apache

I get this error when trying to serve my PHP code from Apache:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: COMMUNITY in
>   /var/www/Account/assets/includes/head/nav.php on line 1
>
> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUser() on
>   null in /var/www/Account/assets/includes/head/nav.php:1 Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/Account/assets/includes/head.php(60): include_once() #1 /var/www/Account/cpanel/community.php(3):
>   include('/var/www/Accoun...') #2
>   /var/www/Account/assets/classes/core.php(14):
>   require_once('/var/www/Accoun...') #3
>   /var/www/Account/assets/includes/head.php(7):
>   require_once('/var/www/Accoun...') #4
>   /var/www/Account/cpanel/home.php(3): include('/var/www/Accoun...') #5
>   {main} thrown in /var/www/Account/assets/includes/head/nav.php on line
>   1

On XAMPP in Windows it's working, I don't get the error; but on Linux with Apache doesn't. Both use PHP 7.1

---

Content in **head.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include_once("config/min.php");

session_start();
define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__);
require_once(ROOTPATH.'/../classes/core.php');

if ($USER->is_logged_in())  {
  $stmt = $USER->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:uid");
  $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
  $U_DATA = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

?>
<html>
  <head>

    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

    <?php include_once("head/styles.php"); ?>

    <?php include_once("config/ads.php"); ?>
  </head>

    <body>
    <?php include_once("head/nav.php"); ?>
```

Content in **core.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';
require_once 'PasswordStorage.php';


require_once 'user.php';
$USER = new USER();

require_once 'community.php';
$COMMUNITY = new COMMUNITY();

?>
```

Content in **nav.php**

```
<?php if (!strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "a/")) { if ($USER->is_logged_in()) { $C_USER = $COMMUNITY->getUser($U_DATA['id']); } ?>
<div class="wrapper">
...
```

Content in **community.php**

```
<?php

class COMMUNITY
{
    private $conn;
    public function __construct() {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    private function request($path) {
        $url = "https://community.makeroid.io";
        $api_key = "XXX";
        $api_user = "system";
        $request = file_get_contents($url."/".$path."?api_key=".$api_key."&api_username=".$api_user);
        if ($request) {
            return json_decode($request, true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function getUser($id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM c_users WHERE u_id=:id;");
        $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (count($user) == 1) {
            return $user[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function verifyUser($username, $id, $email) {
        $emails = $this->request("users/".$username."/emails.json");
        if ($emails) {
            if ($emails['email'] == $email) {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO c_users (u_id, username) VALUES(:uID, :username);");
                $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
                $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
                $stmt->execute();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getUserData($username) {
        $user = $this->request("users/".$username.".json");
        return $user['user'];
    }

    public function getProfilePicture($username) {
        $user = $this->request("users/".$username.".json");
        return "https://community.makeroid.io".$user['user']['avatar_template'];
    }

    public function getId($username) {
        $user = $this->request("users/".$username.".json");
        return $user['user']['id'];
    }

    public function getTrustLevel($username) {
        $user = $this->request("users/".$username.".json");
        return $user['user']['trust_level'];
    }

    public function getTrustLevelRequirements($id) {
        $tl3_requirements = $this->request("admin/users/".$id.".json");
        if ($tl3_requirements['tl3_requirements']) {
            return $tl3_requirements['tl3_requirements'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

---

**Why the $USER and $COMMUNITY aren't shared?**

Comment: you can move the <!doctype html> to before html.

Comment: Could be that there is an issue with the COMMUNITY class constructor that is causing it to return NULL? Try adding **exit('<pre>'.print_r($COMMUNITY,1).'</pre>');** just after the class instantiation in "core.php" and see what output you get on each system.

Comment: is `require_once(ROOTPATH.'/../classes/core.php');` pointed to the right file?

Comment: @Averias Yes it is

Comment: @Nathan If I comment the require_once of the COMMUNITY and the session start it works

Comment: @Nathan I've edited the question and added the community.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed by setting in **core.php**

```
<?php
require_once(ROOTPATH.'/../classes/user.php');
$USER = new USER();

require_once(ROOTPATH.'/../classes/community.php');
$COMMUNITY = new COMMUNITY();
```

It seems like it wasn't getting the proper file